# What is the difference between the Chain of Responsibility and Command Design Behavioral Patterns?

Tags: design-patterns

I have the book *Design Patterns, by Grady Booch*, but I am confused on the difference between the **Chain of Responsibility** and **Command design patterns**? Can anyone offer some clarity?

I am trying to figure out which one to use in a mini server system where you can send a command like `LOGIN <user:pass>` or `ADD_ENTRY <title:description>` or so on, and then I thought I could make a thread where I parse any data coming in and then throw it out to some `commandHandler` or something that would look at the `command` and the data sent with it, and perform an action on it. It seems like either **Chain of Responsibility** or **Command** would work for this, but I am confused on the difference between them.

Can anyone explain?

Comment: Actually Grady Booch wrote the foreword for Design Patterns :)

Comment: There is no commonality between them to compare.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured it out - command is basically just a command encapsulated in an object. Chain of responsibility is more an object trying to handle something & if not, pass it onto the next one in the 'chain'.

Answer (score 2):

In chain of responsibility pattern you do not have the chance to undo, save or queue the actions. If you need to do that you have to use command pattern. If you want to execute te operation in a different time than use command pattern.
If more than one object can handle a request use chain of responsibility.